# Testing a method in MVC which makes calls to Repositories

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I have a MVC method like so:

```
public ActionResult ChangeStatus(string productId, string statusToChange)
{
    var productToChangeStatus = _updateProductRepository.GetUpdateProduct(productId);

    if (statusToChange.ToLower() == ChangeStatusTo.Disable)
    {
        productToChangeStatus.Active = "false";
    }
    else
    {
        productToChangeStatus.Active = "true";
    }

    _updateProductsManager.UpsertProduct(productToChangeStatus);

    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

This method gets an existing product based on the 'productId', changes the 'Active' property on it based on the 'statusToChange' value, saves it back and returns a Json with success.

The test setup is like so:

```
private ProductController _controller;
private Mock<IUpdateProductRepository> _iProductRepository;


[TestInitialize]
public void TestSetup()
{
    _iProductRepository = new Mock<IUpdateProductRepository>();
    _controller = new ProductController(_iProductRepository.Object);
}
```

Wrote a test method like so:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Disable_A_Product_Which_Is_Currently_Enabled()
{
    const string productId = "123";

    var productBeforeStatusChange = new Product()
    {
        Active = "true",
        Id = new Guid().ToString(),
        Name = "TestProduct",
        ProductId = "123"
    };

    var productAfterStatusChange = new Product()
    {
        Active = "false",
        Id = new Guid().ToString(),
        Name = "TestProduct",
        ProductId = "123"
    };

    _iProductRepository.Setup(r => r.GetUpdateProduct(productId)).Returns(productBeforeStatusChange);

    _iProductRepository.Setup(r => r.UpsertProduct(productBeforeStatusChange)).Returns(productAfterStatusChange);

    var res = _controller.ChangeStatus("123", "disable") as JsonResult;
    Assert.AreEqual("{ success = true }", res.Data.ToString());
}
```

The test fails with this error:

```
Object reference not set to an instant of the object.
```

On debugging I found that it fails inside the

```
if(...)
```

condition where the actual setting of the Active property is happening.
Since the productId that's being passed is not real a product object can't be retrieved for the code to work on.

I tried to use Mock but I think my usage is not correct.

So what I want to know is, how to test a method like this where a method that returns an ActionResult is in turn calling the repository to work with object(s).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to be missing setup for

```
_updateProductsManager.UpsertProduct()
```

The way you setup `GetUpdateProduct`() method you ought to setup `UpsertProduct`() on the mock instance.

Comment: @Codehelp - I do not see it. All you did is defined a mock object _iProductsManager. Where is _iProductsManager.Setup() call?

Comment: did the setup as suggested